# Vertical centering element CSS

Tags: css, positioning

In below code how do I do vertical center element span with class "ExclamationPoint" ?
I want to design it like below picture :

I tried Padding-top and vertical; align but I couldn't style like image 
I want to position span with class "ExclamationPoint"  vertically middle regardless the height of side DIV.

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vNDUx/)

[image]

Comment: Take a look here, this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170764/css-vertical-centering-unknown-height-other-content-on-page

Comment: This link is contained in the above question http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Comment: Can't you just use a background-image (which then may be centered vertically) and give the outer box a left-padding? @Mike The linked question has only an answer for fixed-height contents.

Comment: @feeela Its good suggestion. I thinks I should do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force it to the middle of the div like so:

First make sure the parent div (`NewsNote`) has a `position` set, so add `position:relative;`.

Now, you can center `.ExclamationPoint` by giving it a `height` of `0`, `position:absolute;` and `top:50%;`. This will push the div down to the exact middle.

Now the exclamation point will be below the center, to fix this add `line-height:0;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vNDUx/1/

Comment: +1 for a good idea. This solution is not centered exactly in Opera 11.50, but it is in Chromium 13.0.782.215…

Comment: Nice idea, I think I can fix it in opera using Conditional css comments

Comment: Keep in mind that the content shifts off-screen if the browser height is too low.