# html/css box model structure, centering and stuff

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

As always I have difficulties explaining my self, so I've taken the time to create a little presentation:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25916579/drawing.svg

It seemed so easy to begin with, but as always, I'm in over my head here. I suppose javascript could be a solution, but I don't care for it.

I did find a solution that works in chrome and firefox, but not in IE.

NB: I don't care about support for older browsers.

Here's my attempt at solving the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/fLGUh/

As already mentioned, I did get a working solution with chrome and firefox, but it's not exactly perfect.

When taking a look at this in IE, you'll notice that the bottom #fill does not act as expected.

Please let me know if you know about batter way not involving javascript.

Best regards.

edit:
Just for the fun of it, I done some research on how a javascript solution would look like, and apparently it's not as easy as I first thought, so if you want take wack at it, you'll be most welcome.

edit2:
At this point I think I'm forced to accept that a javascript solution may be the only way to go. It's really too bad. I suck at javascript...

edit3:
a working js solution has been presented and a major flaw of mine has been pointed out. I'll be back later when I have the time, to finish this.
Until then, thank you all and best regards.

edit4:
This does exactly what I was looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(
  function() {
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var m = (wh-540)/2;
    if(wh > 540) {
      $('#content').css('margin-top', m).css('margin-bottom', m);
    }
  }
);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: black
}
#content {
  width: 960px;
  min-height: 540px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? and not 'caring for' javascript seems a bit silly as I seem to be under the impression that you wish to vertically center something? this (to do effectively) usually requires js of some sort; although i'm still not quite sure what you are trying to do..

Comment: I'm trying to achieve exactly what I've described. If I haven't done a good enough job of it, please let me know exactly what you do not comprehend, so that I may improved upon my feeble attempt of an explanation as to what goes through my mind. Exactly why I do not care for JavaScript is a long and irrelevant story, but as I've already come very close to solving the problem without it, I hope it is in fact possible.

Comment: Your explanation is simply a document with specifications but it does not explain what you are trying to do.  Please explain more

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand. I've done my best to explain the problem (please let me know if I've failed) and now I simply need a solution. What is missing? Honestly, I do not understand.

Comment: probably a dupe of this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170764/css-vertical-centering-unknown-height-other-content-on-page   But also check out this excellent link by Chris Coyer:  http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first link may be interesting, though I'm not sure just yet. Important to mention that this is not just about centering. The normal Absolute positioning trick won't work as the container element height is no constant. I would work in relation to the top of the viewport, but not the bottom.

Comment: If you read Chris Coyer's article, it talks specifically about if you don't know your container's height as well.

Comment: Yes i is mighty impressive, but I'm interested in a static top and bottom margin. In case your viewport has a height of 1000px, the top and bottom margin should thus be equal to (1000-540)/2 regardless of the content area height and I do not believe the article is any help that regard.

Comment: Hm, I still think I do not understand the question. It contains contradictory statements. Say, the content is 900px high. Viewport is 1000. You want the margin (1000-540)/2 = 230. But to keep the content centered the margin should be 50px.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really talking about centering anything unless the content area is not overflowing and thus has a height higher than the min-height. In short, I want the top and bottom margin to be the same, regardless of the height of the content area, but that margin should be defined using the viewport height and the content area min-height. I realize that this is mighty confusing, especially when I try to explain it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.  I looked at your original jsfiddle and tried removing the 270px margin constraint in your fill div, as you said the bottom fill behaved wrongly in IE.  I see what you mean, in IE9, your height was WAY bigger than the top fill div.  I removed this constraint and it started behaving properly in IE9.  http://jsfiddle.net/fLGUh/3/  BTW, it also works the same in IE7.

Also, your div id="fill" should have been class="fill".

Comment: Doh, for id VS class. That alone could actually be the problem, though further testing is needed of course.  You example however isn't of much use, as it has a margin top/bottom of 50% of the viewport height, which isn't really of much use. 50% viewport - 50% content height is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well then I think the js solution is what you're headed for ;)

Comment: Ya, problem is that I'm an idiot. I'm been researching the problem for hours now. It's really simple: if(viewportHeight <= 540) elementMarginTop = 540; else elementMarginTop = (ViewportHeight-540)/2; but javascript, DOM, and all that crap just don't agree with me. There is no easy way to say it. I'm an idiot...

Comment: LOL.  Dood, I feel EXACTLY the same way about javascript myself, but it's good to have in your web corner.....

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbin.com/afemaz/ - works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE>=8. Unlike your solution, it doesn't crop the top part of the content when the window is small.

Comment: Sorry, but no it does not. as the height of the content area increases, the top and bottom margin decreases, which is not the intention.

Comment: Margin defined using the viewport height and the content area min-height: http://jsbin.com/ogahiq It would be interesting to know how you want to use it.

Comment: I'm not actual sure it will work in the real world, but it does matter much. At this point in time I'm only experimenting. Anyway, apart from the content area not actually having a min-height in your example, it seem to do exactly what I was looking for, so huge ty for that. I still have a few things to test before concluding anything, but it seems that your are the great savior of the day. Have to go selebrate a birthday now, but will be back later to finish this.

Comment: Apparently I was mistaken. It does not infact work... Oh well I'm tired of this. Just gonna figure out the best answer and do something else. Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Vertically centering with variable heights is not possible with only HTML/CSS, you'll need JS.

What you can try is:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="width:960px; height:540px; margin:10px auto;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    if(h > 560) //window is smaller: use the minimal settings as defined in style
    {
        d.style.marginTop = (h - 540) / 2;
    }
</script>
```

`window.innerHeight` stores (with some controversy across browsers I think) the actual currently available display space. `getElementById`accesses the div. Its `style.marginTop` (and `marginBottom`) as well as `style.height` let you control those dimensions.

Caveats:

- The script needs to be below the div as otherwise the script will run but the div doesn't exist yet (which makes it ineffective).
- The margin is defined once while loading. If you resize the window afterwards, it won't adjust.

Comment: I'm sorry. but this don't seem to work for me. Looking at the code it should work more or less as I want it too, but apparently it has no affect. Mind you, I'm an idiot when it comes to js.

Comment: Are you using IE8 or lower? According to W3Schools those are the only browsers not supporting `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Currently I'm using chromium, though IE8 support might be a requirement. I'm not sure how many are actually using it. Anyway, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I am after all a js noob.

Comment: Try literally just making an empty file, copy and paste my sample, save as test.htm and open it in the browser. It works in FF for me; I'm not sure what's keeping it from working on jsFiddle.

Comment: @Zacariaz, at least half of your site visitors will be using IE of some kind, which is why web devs are still pulling their hair out over IE.  ;)